# How to unit test cookie expiration in Karma / Jasmine / Phantom JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cookies, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for a simple javascript...

- Karma v1.5.0
- Jasmine v2.5.3
- PhantomJS v2.1.14

I'm trying to write a test to ensure that a cookie is getting the proper expiration date (30 days). Recent versions of Jasmine support faking the passage of time using [jasmine.clock()](https://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Jasmine_Clock) but this doesn't appear to work on cookie expiration...

```
describe("cookies...", function () {

    it("expire after 30 days", function () {

        jasmine.clock().install();

        set_a_cookie_to_expire_in_30_days();

        jasmine.clock().tick(29 *24*60*60*1000); //fast forward 29 days

        expect(check_cookie()).toBeTruthy();

        jasmine.clock().tick(2 *24*60*60*1000); //fast forward another 2 days

        expect(check_cookie()).toBeFalsy(); //THIS FAILS

        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });

});
```

The second `expect()` fails. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Jasmine clock `tick` won't actually affect time passing in the browser. It will only execute callbacks for setTimeouts or setIntervals.

From their docs:

> The Jasmine Clock is available for a test suites that need the ability to use setTimeout or setInterval callbacks. It makes the timer callbacks synchronous, executing the registered functions only once the clock is ticked forward in time. This makes timer-related code much easier to test.

You should instead use `mockDate`.

```
jasmine.clock().mockDate(
  new Date(2018, 5, 11)
);
```

Where you tick forward 29 days, you can simply `mockDate` again 29 days forward. Hope this helps!